# Reference and Value Comparison

Tags: kotlin

Actually, I am new to kotlin; therefore, this question may be very basic.

According to kotlin documentation, two variables can be compared with `===` and `==` operators. 
First one ('==') checks if they have same content or not, and the second one ('+==') checks if they have same reference or not. 
However, I cannot find any built-in class whose objects have same content, but with different references.

```
var str1 : String = "Hello World"
var str2 : String = "Hello World"

if( str1 == str2 ){ // yes
   print("Their contents are same\n")
{

if( str1 === str2 ){ // yes
   print("Their references are same\n")
}
```

Instances of all classes I have encountered up to now have same reference if their contents are same. How do we define two objects which have same content, but different references ?

Comment: second case will compare same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Reference equality](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html#referential-equality)

> Referential equality is checked by the `===` operation (and its negated counterpart `!==`). `a === b` evaluates to true if and only if a and b point to the same object.

In other words the `===` operator compares if `a` and `b` are the same reference. Using it on some basic types can be misleading because of:

- [string interning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-string-interning)
- [integer caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897020/why-integer-class-caching-values-in-the-range-128-to-127)

An example would be:

```
val a:Int? = 123
val b:Int? = 123
println(a === b) // => true

val c:Int? = 130
val d:Int? = 130
println(c === d) // => false
```

Obviously in both cases the `a == b` and `c == d` is true.

[Since string interning is also possible at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879179/is-string-interning-done-at-compile-time-in-java) the `===` also returns `true` in simple scenarios:

```
val a = "ala"
val b = "ala"
println(a === b) // => true

val c = "!ala".substring(1)
val d = "!ala".substring(1)
println(c === d) // => false
```

### [Structural equality](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html#structural-equality)

> Structural equality is checked with the `==` operator (and its negated counterpart `!=`). By convention, an expression like `a == b` is translated to:
>
> `a?.equals(b) ?: (b === null)`

As we saw above it is perfectly normal for built-in classes like `String` and `Int` to return false for reference equality `===` even though their contents are equal. Kotlin lets us define classes which can easily be checked for structural equality with `data classes` like so:

```
data class Address(val city:String, val street1:String)

val a = Address("Warsaw", "Jagielońska")
val b = Address("Warsaw", "Jagielońska")

println(a === b) // => false
println(a == b) // => true
```

Answer (score 2):

The === is not working because of the way you are defining the String. If you create a string using a literal, it will point to the same String in the String pool.

```
var str1 = "Hello World"
    var str2 = "Hello World"
    val str3 = buildString { "Hello World" }
    val str4 = buildString { "Hello World" }

    var result = str1===str2 // true
    println(result)

    result = str1 == str2 // true
    println(result)

    result = str3 === str4 // false
    println(result)

    result = str3 == str4 // true
    println(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Comparing `String` references like that will return `true`, because the JVM optimizes your example code by reusing the first `String` instance, since it's immutable anyway. See more discussion about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3801343/4465208), for example.

If you call the constructor of a class directly however, you'll skip any optimizations, and get different instances:

```
val i1 = Integer(1)
val i2 = Integer(1)

println(i1 == i2)  // true
println(i1 === i2) // false
```

Sidenote: in Java, I'd have shown this example with `new String("Hello world")`, but apparently the Kotlin `String` class doesn't have a constructor of that form. Strange.